# Cloning a cvs repository client-side

Tags: git, cvs

I would like to clone a cvs repository from sourceforge with all it's branches and history ([this one](http://sourceforge.net/p/beecrypt/code/?source=navbar)) in particular.

I've tried using `git cvsimport`, but this does not support `cvsps` v3, and other answers here say that `cvsexport` does a more complete import into git.

But `cvsexport` requires RCS files, how do I get those client-side? When checking out a CVS repository only the head revision is checked out, and I don't have admin access so can't use rsync.

I don't have any CVS experience btw, only GIT experience.

[EDIT] Just found out that sourceforge has anonymous `rsync` access via the `rsync://` protocol, so my original problem is solved. **However**, what if it didn't support this?

Answer (score 1):

I know the OP found the answer, but I decided to post this for the benefit of those who found this by searching, like me.

In the case of SourceForge, this link explains how to back up a CVS repository.

http://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/CVS/#backups

As of this writing:

> Backups of a CVS repository may be made using rsync.
>
> Example (replace PROJECTNAME with the UNIX group name of your project):

```
rsync -av rsync://PROJECTNAME.cvs.sourceforge.net/cvsroot/PROJECTNAME/* .
```